# proprety volumes of docker compose it's not updaing my files

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, volumes

I created my docker-compose e runs just fine, but when I edit a file, the change doesn't go to the container,btw I'm new at docker so sorry if I'm using the wrong words

```
services:
  front:
    build: ./reactualtor
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./reactualtor:/getting-started-with-docker/front
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/getting-started-with-docker/api
```

My folder structure

```
api
Dockerfile
 src
 index.ts
package.json

front
Dockerfile
 src
 index.ts
package.json
```

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding the code built into the image, so if you rebuild your images and restart the containers, you won't actually see the updated code.  I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` blocks.

Comment: i didn't understand anything

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly, there is nothing wrong with the docker compose. the problem is in the lib I'm using ts-node-dev, I  have to add a flag called --poll and then it works fine